# I have a 256gb SSD primary and 1TB HDD secondary - best to store the home folder where?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, home-directory

I've got a 256GB SSD primary and 1TB HDD secondary. I've already gone through the steps of storing my large Dropbox folder on the secondary. I can at the moment easily fit the home folder on the primary, but was wondering if it's better placed on the secondary given the read/write wear on a SSD.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,

M

Comment: This would depend on what as well as how much data you have and plan on storing on your drives and how you use it. If you edit video or image files frequently (huge files in general) you might want to use the improved speeds of ssds however, storing a lot of them fills it up pretty quickly.

Comment: Wondering about this also. Yes it depends on how big the /home folder is. There is nothing to prevent you from keeping text-based documents, and even images on the SSD, but save all large files, especially videos, to a partition on the HDD.

Comment: I say just mount a new folder within /home that's mapped to a larger drive, and save large files there. I've had an SSD for 3yrs+ no signs of wear, SSD volatility isn't anything to be worried about, you'll upgrade again before it goes bad.

Comment: Thanks so much folks - I really appreciate these suggestions!